# Using the Datomic pull in a Query

Tags: clojure, datomic

According to line 54 of the 'geting-started.clj' file which ships with Datomic (under samples/seattle) I should be able to use the pull function inside a query like so:

```
(def pull-results (q '[:find (pull ?c [*]) :where [?c :community/name]] (db conn)))
```

However, in my code below I get an error: IllegalArgumentException Argument [*] in :find is not a variable  datomic.query/validate-query (query.clj:315)

```
(defn get-tag [] (d/q '[:find (d/pull ?e [*])
                        :where [?e :tag.tag/term]] (db conn)))
```

Now, to my eyes these two are similarly constructed. Coupled with the fact that the pull function api as read from http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/pull appears to be:

```
(pull db pattern eid)
```

I would say that the API has changed since the Seattle code was written. Am I correct? If not, what is going on here. Thanks

Comment: remove the `d/` from `d/pull` is my guess. It's syntax in this case.

Comment: thanks! that fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the commenter points out, the issue is passing the `datomic.api/pull` function instead of using a pull expression. Some points of clarification:

You're not invoking the `pull` function inside of query, but using a special expression called the `pull` [expression](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#pull-expressions) inside a `find` clause. Note that query accepts a data structure literal (why you have to use `quote`/`'`). The `pull` expression is part of the [query grammar](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#grammar) and something the datalog parser recognizes, not a direct invocation of the pull function in the Datomic API which has a different invocation.